# Check if Excel file contains formula

Tags: python, excel

So my company is trying to analyze a few hundred thousand Excel files to detect which ones contain formulas. I was just wondering if this was possible using Python(assuming it is) and if so what packages and strategies would you recommend to accomplish this?

Comment: This is a really broad question, but I'd start by checking out http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: I would test a range of cells to see if they start with "=" as that is always the first character of a formula, whatever the formula....

Answer (score 4):

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book = load_workbook(filename='your_file_name')
sheet = book[book.sheetnames[0]]
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1):
    line = []
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.data_type)
```

Buy using the `openpyxl` package you can figure it out. if the cell is formula it's data_type will be `f`